# How to use mysql.connector in Python 2.6

Tags: mysql-python, python-2.6

I'm using Python 2.6 in centos. I'm trying to connect with MySQL server. I've tried pip install mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python and mysql-connector-python-rf yet I can't mysql_connector.so not found in pip libs. I get error: module not found MySQL.connector!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try below:
    pip install mysql-connector=2.1.4